# Can't connect to public cloud server via http/https in OVH

Tags: domain-name-system, http, cloud, reverse-dns, ovh

I'm new to OVH and trying to setup a site inside a public cloud server. I've got the server up and running and i can SSH into it, but can't get to port 80. (server has apache running and it can be accessed from inside the server). if i curl i get a port 80: No route to host. Browser says ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE. Tried disabling the firewall as well with no luck.

PS I can see that i don't have a reverse-dns set up. Could that be the problem?

UPDATE :

- Curl Command : `curl <ip>:80`
- SSH Command : `ssh user@<ip> -i my_key`

Comment: I can see that my predecessor has set up reverse dns to ip-<first-3-octets>.eu for existing servers. I have no idea how that happens but those servers work.

Comment: What are the CURL and SSH commands you are using to access the server? Please add the commands to the question.

Comment: Those reverse DNS entries are the defaults that OVH provide for new servers. They're also totally irrelevant to this question.

Comment: Check for an OVH cloud firewall attached to your server.